# Spring ROO database reverse engineering with renamed context file

Tags: maven, primefaces, eclipselink, reverse-engineering, spring-roo

My requirement is quite simple. I recently created a jsf-primefaces-spring-roo-eclipselink multi module archetype and distributed it across my team here. With Spring ROO enabled, it makes our life easier to do all database reverse engineering and all is happy and well.

When I created the archetype, I used an applicationContext.xml file in the model tier to do ROO DB reverse engineering. I then tried to change the name of the context file to applicationContext-model.xml because I used another context in the web tier. Now after renaming this context file, when I do a 'database reverse engineer --schema ', I get 'unable-to-obtain-connection' when I tab for autocomplete in the roo shell. Also when I enter my schema name manually after --schema, I get this error:

**File 'C:\TestWorkspace\TT\TT-model\src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml' does not exist**

Obviously ROO doesn't seem so happy with the context file rename. May I know how I could tell ROO to take the new context file name to do the database reverse engineering?

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Basith

Answer (score 1):

Since Roo wants a context file in the path 'src\main\resources\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml', I usually change the name of the other context files if I need to avoid collisions.

For instance, try to rename the application context file that you have in the web tier.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation jbbarquero. Didn't know Roo had such a restriction.

Comment: Actually I'm not right. I'm currently trying the new version, 1.2.3, and now it's allowed to change the name of the application context file. It's better to use a name that follow the pattern used by the tests: applicationContext*.xml, but I still don't try reverse engineer.

Comment: Hi jbbarquero. I used applicationContext*.xml pattern in web.xml to include all context files that belong to this application. Everything is fine except for ROO DBRE. And Roo doesn't let me have anything other than applicationContext.xml for it's DBRE magic to work. Please do let me know if you find a way to hack it out :) Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've reviewed the Roo DBRE command and it has hardcoded the name "applicationContext.xml" for searching the JNDI DS name in order to connect to the DB. In fact, if there it doesn't exist, it uses the "database.properties" file (yes, hardcoded too). You could raise a JIRA ticket, because it doesn't even appear in the documentation (http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html). NOTE :the pattern in the web.xml is used for loading the application context for the web application, it has nothing to do with the addons, including DBRE. So the 1st workaround should work